# How do I compile a 64-bit c++ prog using code blocks Ubuntu

Tags: c++, 64-bit, codeblocks, ubuntu-11.10

I have a multithreaded c++ code, I am trying to compile it using code blocks on 64-ubuntu, for 32-bit compilation I gave -m32 and it works good but for 64-bit I gave -m64 and it failed. I am using

```
#elif defined(__ia64__) && defined(__GNUC__)
```

it simply unable to recognize it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you SURE you want to use "ia64"? In most cases, that refers to Itanium CPUs; you probably meant to check for  __x86_64 or __amd64 or something similar.

EDIT: Which still leaves the question why you want to check for a specific CPU.

Comment: thanx for your quick response. Boss in my code I am using an open source 3rd part lib for high performance computing, the checks are already there and for 64-bit it is the only option...

Comment: also for 32-bit using flag -m32 the below check works good #elif defined(__i386__) && defined(__GNUC__)

Comment: I have observed that it is targeted at x86_64 , now can any one help me how can i set target compiler ia64 using code blocks